# File upload to SFTP using ASP.net c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to upload files to SFTP using c# with third party lib(Tamir.SharpSsh).

i am getting the below error. Please advice.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(String hostName)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.java.net.Socket..ctor(String host, Int32 port)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Util.createSocket(String host, Int32 port, Int32 timeout)
```

Below are my code:

```
using Tamir.SharpSsh;
using Tamir.Streams;
using Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch;
```

call this function:

```
private static void UploadFileToFTP(string file_name)
    {
        string sftp_Servername = "https://xxx.ftpxxx.com/";
        string sftp_username = "username";
        string sftp_password = "password";
        int sftp_port = 22;

        Sftp SFTP = new Sftp(sftp_Servername, sftp_username, sftp_password);
        SFTP.Connect();
        SFTP.Put(file_name, sftp_Servername);
    }
```

Thanks,

Mugundhan R

the above was worked fine only.. but suddenly this error is coming

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target         machine actively refused it 46.16.160.16:22
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress    socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.java.net.Socket..ctor(String host, Int32 port)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Util.createSocket(String host, Int32 port, Int32 timeout)
```

Comment: At minimum, you'll have to show us some of your code. We can't see what you don't show us, and we can't debug a problem without seeing the code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
string sftp_Servername = "https://xxx.ftpxxx.com/";
```

to

```
string sftp_Servername = "xxx.ftpxxx.com";
```